# How is this done? $2i+((1/2)-i)^2=((1/2)+i)^2$

Tags: calculus

Can someone please explain me how this is done?

$$\ 2i+\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)^2$$

Comment: Have you tried multiplying it out?

Comment: Yes did that, but then I get -(3/4) + i

Comment: Edit your post to show your calculation...that'll make it easier for people to help.  My guess:  you are handling the sign on $i^2$ incorrectly.

Comment: I solved it, haqnatural's suggestion helped me

Comment: @Complex_Number If so, be sure to accept the answer which helped you best by clicking on the checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\ 2i+\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right)^2=2i+\frac{1}{4}-i+i^2=\frac{1}{4}+i+i^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)^2$$

No need to use $i^2=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that $${ i }^{ 2 }=-1\\ { \left( a+b \right)  }^{ 2 }={ a }^{ 2 }+2ab+{ b }^{ 2 }$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2i+(\tfrac12-i)^2=2i+(\tfrac12)^2-2(\tfrac12)(i) +(i)^2$$
$$=2i+\tfrac14-i+(-1)$$
$$=-\tfrac34+i$$
On the other hand,
$$(\tfrac12+i)^2=(\tfrac12)^2+2(\tfrac12)(i) +(i)^2$$
$$=\tfrac14+i+(-1)$$
$$=-\tfrac34+i$$
which is the same as the first value.